# I would like to display an audio spectrum on the screen while a user is recording in my voice recorder app, how can I go about this?

Tags: java, android, audio, mediarecorder

In my voice recorder Android application, a user can press a button to start recording and then another to stop their recording.

Of course, this is very boring and I would like to implement a live audio wave spectrum that represents the input to the MediaRecorder while they are recording their file.

[image: This is screenshot] is what the screen looks like at the moment.

I can't find anything to help me implement this online, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Search for `Audio visualizer android` .. You will find some awesome work ..

Comment: @ADM Ah I feel silly now. Weird that I never came across this library while looking for an answer. Thank you.